# Skyrim: The White Phial - Refilling Times?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just completed & repaired the white phial, and I chose healing, and I tested it out but now the phial is "empty" and under miscellaneous. I have tried waiting but it won't refill. Do I need a special item to refill it with or not?

Comment: PC or Console??

Answer (score 2):

Normally, it should take [24 hours to refill](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_White_Phial_(item)).  And you shouldn't need any special items it does it by itself.

However, there is a bug that make break the item:

> After the phial refills, the empty phials will remain in your inventory. If you try to delete extra empty phials, the white phial may not refill.